# Python Streamplot from large 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot streamtraces from CFD analysis with Python, over a 2D contour plot. My problem is that I'm dealing with 4 large 1D arrays (x,y coordinates and u,v velocity components), say over 100k points, arising from an external CFD simulation (so I cannot manipulate them). Creating 2D arrays from them (e.g. with scipy.interpolate.griddata as I found) causes my computer to crash due to excessive memory usage.
I've also tried with quiver but I can't get a size for the arrows that scales with the dimensions of the plot: they are either too big or too small and anyway too many.

Since I've looked at all the solutions I've found but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

try to vectorize your loops that may help greatly with large scale datas.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than answer.